# How to make detail page in React?

Tags: reactjs

Currently, I'm making a system that can control home electrical equipment on the web.
Backend is ready,
I made a page to display a list of all devices with React
but when I tried to create a detail page from there,
I am stumbling.

How can I write it so that only the details of the device clicked on DeviceList.js (device list page) can be displayed with CameraDetail.js?

The information that can be obtained with the API is as follows.
(There are still various devices, but I show only a cameras now.)

***Json***

```
    "attributes": {
        "camera": [
            {
                "entity_id": "camera_1",
                "object_id": "AMC0570066109434BF",
                "home": "api/services/home",
                "away": "api/services/away",
                "image": "services/camera_proxy/camera_1",
                "live_stream": "services/camera_proxy_stream/camera_1",
                "mode": "Home",
                "room_name": "Main",
                "state": "Home",
                "stream": "services/camera_proxy_stream/camera_1",
                "is_failed": false,
                "rank": 0,
                "disabled": false
            },
            {
                "entity_id": "camera_3",
                "object_id": "Z104E0A3476D0",
                "home": "api/services/home",
                "away": "api/services/away",
                "image": "services/camera_proxy/camera_3",
                "live_stream": "services/camera_proxy_stream/camera_3",
                "mode": "Home",
                "room_name": "Unassigned Devices",
                "state": "Home",
                "stream": "services/camera_proxy_stream/camera_3",
                "is_failed": false,
                "rank": 0,
                "disabled": false
            },
            {
                "entity_id": "camera_4",
                "object_id": "AMC057ED147BD72134",
                "home": "api/services/home",
                "away": "api/services/away",
                "image": "services/camera_proxy/camera_4",
                "live_stream": "services/camera_proxy_stream/camera_4",
                "mode": null,
                "room_name": "Garage",
                "state": null,
                "stream": "services/camera_proxy_stream/camera_4",
                "is_failed": false,
                "rank": 0,
                "disabled": false
            },
            {
                "entity_id": "camera_2",
                "object_id": "AMC05723DA911E755D",
                "home": "api/services/home",
                "away": "api/services/away",
                "image": "services/camera_proxy/camera_2",
                "live_stream": "services/camera_proxy_stream/camera_2",
                "mode": null,
                "room_name": "Unassigned Devices",
                "state": null,
                "stream": "services/camera_proxy_stream/camera_2",
                "is_failed": true,
                "rank": 0,
                "disabled": false
            }
        ],
.
.
.
```

***CameraDetail.js***

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, onClick} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import Cookies from 'universal-cookie';
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { useParams, Link, useHistory } from 'react-router-dom'

import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { setUserID } from "../stores/user";


const cookies = new Cookies();

const CameraDetail = () => {
  const history = useHistory();

  const [camera, setCamera] = useState([]);

  const isLoggedIn= useSelector(state => state.user.isLoggedIn);


const getDevices = async(data) => {
  await axios.get('example.com/devices',
    {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${cookies.get('accesstoken')}`
      },
    })
    .then(result => {
      setCamera(result.data.attributes.camera);  
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
    });
}

useEffect(() => {
  getDevices();
},[]);


  return (
    <div className="container">
      {isLoggedIn ? 
      <div className="row mx-auto text-center">
        <>
        ???????????
        </>
      </div>
      :
      <div>
          <p> You should login</p>
      </div>
      }
    </div>
  );
}
export default CameraDetail;
```

***Default.js***

```
import { Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Top from './Top';
import Signup from './Signup';
import Login from './Login';
import DeviceList from './DeviceList';
import CameraDetail from './CameraDetail';


class Default extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
              <div className="main">
                  <Switch>
                      <Route exact path="/" component={Top} />
                      <Route exact path="/signup" component={Signup} />
                      <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
                      <Route exact path="/device_list" component={DeviceList} />
                      <Route exact path="/camera_detail/" component={CameraDetail.js} />
                      <Route render={() => <p>not found!.</p>} />
                  </Switch>
              </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
export default Default;
```

***DeviceList.js***

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, onClick} from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import Cookies from 'universal-cookie';
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { useParams, Link, useHistory } from 'react-router-dom'

import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { setUserID } from "../stores/user";

const cookies = new Cookies();

const DeviceList = () => {
  const history = useHistory();

  const [camera, setCamera] = useState([]);

  const {id} = useParams();
  const isLoggedIn= useSelector(state => state.user.isLoggedIn);
  const userID= useSelector(state => state.user.userID);


const getDevices = async(data) => {
  await axios.get('example.com/devices',
    {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${cookies.get('accesstoken')}`
      },
    })
    .then(result => {
      setCamera(result.data.attributes.camera);  
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log(err);
    });
}

useEffect(() => {
  getDevices();
},[]);


  return (
    <div className="container">
    <div className="row mx-auto">
      <div className="col-md-4 mx-auto text-center">
      {isLoggedIn ? 
      <div>
          <p>Camera List</p>
          <div>
                {camera.map((item,i) => 
                  <div key={i}>
                    <p>-------</p>
                    <p>Entity Id: {item.entity_id}</p>
                    <p>Object Id: {item.object_id}</p>
                    <p>Home: {item.home}</p>
                    <p>Away: {item.away}</p>
                    <p>Image: {item.image}</p>
                    <p>is_failed: {item.is_failed}</p>
                    <p>Live Stream: {item.live_stream}</p>
                    <p>Rank: {item.rank}</p>
                    <p>Room Name: {item.room_name}</p>
                    <p>State: {item.state}</p>
                  </div>
                )}
          </div>
      </div>
      :
      <div>
          <p> You should login</p>
      </div>
      }
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
  );
}
export default DeviceList;
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, all the cameras are listed in `DeviceList`, and upon clicking one you want `DeviceDetail` to display information about the specific camera. You have a few options:

### Separate Page

If `DeviceDetail` is a separate page, then you can place it under something like `/camera_detail/:id`. Upon mounting, fetch the details for the specific camera id (which you can read from the page url manually or using something like `react-router`). Notice that currently the `CameraDetail` component is fetching all devices, rather than any specific one.
Navigate to this page by either adding an `onClick` to your list items, or making them into `<a>` elements.
You would also have to fix your routing:

**Default.js**

```js
  <Route exact path="/camera_detail/:id" component={CameraDetail} />
```

### Not Separate Page

If `DeviceDetail` is a component (like a pop-up), it can just take the selected device through props. So for example:

**DeviceList.js**

```js
...

  const [selectedDeviceId, setSelectedDeviceId] = useState()

...

  <div key={i} onClick={() => setSelectedDeviceId(item.id)}

...

  <DeviceDetail device={camera.find(item => item.id === selectedDeviceId)} />

...
```

**DeviceDetail.js**

```js
...

const CameraDetail = (props) => {
  const { device } = props;
  // now you have you selected camera in the component

...
```

Comment: Thank you. 

1, How Can I fix <Link to={`/camera_detail/`}> ? 

2, How can I show camera in DeviceDetail.js which user clicks in DeviceList.js

Comment: 1. Your path should be `/camera_detail/some-camera-id`, 2. `DeviceDetail` should grab the ID from the path, then make an API call to get the relevant item info.

Answer (score 0):

I passed

Default.js

```
Before: <Route exact path="/device_detail/" component={DeviceDetail} />

After: <Route path="/device_detail/:entity_id" component={DeviceDetail} />
```

CameraDetail.js

```
const { entity_id } = useParams();


  return (
    <div className="container">
      {isLoggedIn ? 
      <div className="row mx-auto text-center">
          <>

                {camera.filter(c => c.entity_id === entity_id).map((item,i) => 
                  <div key={i} className="discover_device col-4">
                    <div className="box h-100">
                    <p>{item.room_name}</p>
                    <p>{item.entity_id}</p>
                    <Link to={`/device_list`} className='btn btn-primary col-4'>Back</Link>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                )}
          </>
      </div>
      :
      <div>
          <p> You should login</p>
      </div>
      }
    </div>
  );
```

DeviceList.js

```
Before: <Link to={`/camera_detail/`}>
After: <Link to={`/camera_detail/${item.entity_id}`}>
```